# Why do we need three dots in this append function call?

Tags: go

I'm following a tutorial to learn Rest APIs in Go. There is this piece of code.

```
func removeBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    params := mux.Vars(r)
    id, _ := strconv.Atoi(params["id"])

    for i, item := range books {
        if item.ID == id {
            books = append(books[:i], books[i+1:]...)
        }
    }
}
```

Especially this part `books = append(books[:i], books[i+1:]...)`.

OK, `append` appends one or more items to a slice (in this case to `books` which is a slice of `book` structs). `books[:i]` gets everything from start until the `i`, excluding `i`. Then `i+1` means the next item after `i` and adding a colon to the right means everything from there till the end. So it means we are getting all the items till `i` excluding `i` and then all the items after `i`. Which means we are excluding/removing `i`, and that's the point of `removeBook` function.

I got this much logic, but what are the three dots doing there? I know three dots are used in variadic functions, but why do we need three dots here in this append function?

When I remove these 3 dots, my editor says "***cannot use books[i + 1:] (value of type []Book) as Book value in argument to append***".

If you want to see the complete code, it's in  [this gist](https://gist.github.com/pillaiindu/e386e24ad430ffea29b3c1a3452065b8) .

Comment: To add the whole slice.

Comment: Append is a variadic function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the append defintion [here](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append).

```
func append(slice []Type, elems ...Type) []Type
```

In second argument it is accepting multiple 'elems'.

In the example that you have given it is essentially **passing elements as comma separated parameter list**.

So let's say length of book is 10, and i is 7. Then it passes first 7 elements in slice (items 0 to 6) and then passing 8th and 9th as a comma separated list.

```
books = append(books[:i], books[i+1:]...)
```

is actually

```
 books = append(books[:7], books[8], books[9])
```

Answer (score 1):

```golang
// The append built-in function appends elements to the end of a slice. If
// it has sufficient capacity, the destination is resliced to accommodate the
// new elements. If it does not, a new underlying array will be allocated.
// Append returns the updated slice. It is therefore necessary to store the
// result of append, often in the variable holding the slice itself:
//  slice = append(slice, elem1, elem2)
//  slice = append(slice, anotherSlice...)
// As a special case, it is legal to append a string to a byte slice, like this:
//  slice = append([]byte("hello "), "world"...)
func append(slice []Type, elems ...Type) []Type
```

So, you can only append **Element** but not the whole slice.